# Implement three state checkbox using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, checkbox

I am trying to implement a tri-state checkbox using LWC input type=checkbox element and I am trying to set HTML 5 `indeterminate` attribute https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#checkbox-state-(type%3Dcheckbox) but looks like it is not supported, should I change lightning:input to html basic input?

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" indeterminate={checkboxmodel.indeterminate} checked={checkboxmodel.checked}></lightning-input>
```

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Unknown
>   public property "indeterminate" of element . This is
>   likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "indeterminate".]

Answer (score 5):

Indeterminate is not a content attribute, as per the documentation, it cannot be used in the component's markup

> In addition to the checked and unchecked states, there is a third
>   state a checkbox can be in: indeterminate. This is a state in which
>   it's impossible to say whether the item is toggled on or off. This is
>   set using the HTMLInputElement object's indeterminate property via
>   JavaScript (it cannot be set using an HTML attribute):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: it doesn't allow me to switch to html input, it claims that it doesn't support standard indeterminate attribute for html input

Comment: O.o, I see, it doesnt look like indeterminate is actually a content attribute, so, you cant declare it in the markup

Answer (score 1):

As of now, no direct attribute/property for `indeterminate` is available for the `lightning-input` component as per [the component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification).

There was however mention of an indeterminate state in the SLDS. However, I could not figure it out -

Here's the excerpt from the [SLDS site](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/) -

> As SLDS checkboxes rely on the :checked pseudo selector, and the
> indeterminate state is only accessible via JavaScript, the use of a
> CSS class on the input will be necessary to implement this in SLDS.
> Use JavaScript to add the class when the indeterminate property is set
> to true on the input.

So I ended up doing a workaround by using the simple HTML input -

```html
<div class="slds-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllOpted" id="selectAllOpted" onchange={handleSelectAllOpted}/>
    <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="selectAllOpted">
        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux" style="margin-right: 0.5rem;"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Select All</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Using javascript, populating/changing states -

```js
const selectAllCheckbox = this.template.querySelector('[name="selectAllOpted"]');
selectAllCheckbox.indeterminate = !allAreOpted;
```